# How to automatically create symmetric object on Django's ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to create a symmetric relationship on my model and also add a field in the relationship. I came across [this blog](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/) (and also [this another blog](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/08/14/creating-recursive-symmetrical-many-to-many-relationships-in-django/)) and followed the steps in creating my own models.

```
class CreditCardIssuer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=256)
    transfer_limits = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Balancetransfer', related_name='no_transfer_allowed+', symmetrical=False, help_text=_('List of issuers to which balance transfer is not allowed.'))

    def add_balancetransfer(self, creditcardissuer, until):
        balance_transfer, _newly_created = Balancetransfer.objects.get_or_create(
            no_transfer_from=self,
            no_transfer_to=creditcardissuer,
            until=until)
        balance_transfer, _newly_created = Balancetransfer.objects.get_or_create(
            no_transfer_from=creditcardissuer,
            no_transfer_to=self,
            until=until)
        return balance_transfer

    def remove_balancetransfer(self, creditcardissuer, until):
        Balancetransfer.objects.filter(
            no_transfer_from=self, 
            no_transfer_to=creditcardissuer,
            until=until).delete()
        Balancetransfer.objects.filter(
            no_transfer_from=self, 
            no_transfer_to=creditcardissuer,
            until=until).delete()
        return

    def get_transfer_limits(self, until):
        return self.transfer_limits.filter(
            no_transfer_to__until=until, 
            no_transfer_to__no_transfer_from=self)


class Balancetransfer(models.Model):
    no_transfer_from = models.ForeignKey('CreditCardIssuer', related_name='no_transfer_from')
    no_transfer_to = models.ForeignKey('CreditCardIssuer', related_name='no_transfer_to')
    until = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Minimum card ownership period to allow balance transfer.')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('no_transfer_from', 'no_transfer_to')
```

But when I create the relationship from admin, only one is created. Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate a bit more in detail what you mean with _only one is created_? Or specify what you expect to happen?

Comment: The function CreditCardIssuer.add_balancetransfer shows what I want to accomplish when I create a relationship from admin. That way the relationship will be created for both objects. Thanks for taking time to solve it.

Comment: Two relationships will not be created "automatically" -- I am not 100% clear though on what behavior you're expecting.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: There is no magic, IIRC, you need to invoke `balance_transfer` and `remove_balancetransfer` or do `get_or_create` explicitly, for example in signal handler of [`m2m_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed).

Comment: Why not just use a `symmetric=True` m2m-to-self field and let Django do the symmetric work for you? Or is it because you want the `until` field? In that case, how are you creating the m2m relationship from admin? (Admin won't handle `symmetric=False` m2m-to-self fields, will it?)

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I am creating the objects from admin in a normal way. I was expecting that there is a way to automatically invoke those 2 methods, and thinking that maybe I named them incorrectly (but I guess I was wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you've got one half of this in the Django admin (you don't say how, but I'll assume it works unless you post the code): the remaining step is to set up the half of the relationship that's missing.

I suspect that if you put a breakpoint in your `add_balancetransfer()` method (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`), you'll find that it is never being called — the part of the relation that *is* created is done through built-in Django admin behaviour.

In short, you might just need to call `add_balancetransfer()` yourself when the model is saved — or, better yet, a different version that only adds the missing relationship.

One way to do this is [overriding the model's `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods), but this can be a little fragile. For your situation, it may work better to fill in the missing relationship in the [model's `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/signals/#post-save):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from yourapp.models import CreditCardIssuer

@receiver(post_save, sender=CreditCardIssuer)
def add_missing_relationship(sender, **kwargs):
    # Add the other side of what should be a symmetrical relationship
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I already added some logging within those methods and confirmed that they are never called. If there is no automatic way to create the reverse relationship object, maybe I'll go with overriding save() method.

Comment: @supervacuo looks like a typo. Your import is for post_save and your reciever uses pre_save.